# Prevent traffic to mac address using ebtables

Tags: firewall, ping, mac-address

I have an interface on a remote host:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,10000> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:05:68:02:68:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.3.1/24 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global eth0
```

and on my local machine I have:

```
2: eth6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:13:3b:0f:24:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.3.150/24 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global eth6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::213:3bff:fe0f:24fc/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And do:

```
ebtables -A OUTPUT -d 00:05:68:02:68:dd -j DROP
```

So I get:

```
Bridge chain: OUTPUT, entries: 1, policy: ACCEPT
-d 0:5:68:2:68:dd -j DROP
```

I do the above in order to block all communication to mac address
(on remote interface) **00:05:68:02:68:dd**

However I can still ping my remote interface using 192.168.3.1.
Why? Do I have to enable eptables somehow or something?

Comment: Are they  on the same IP range?

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ebtables* acts only on frames going through a bridge interface.

If you want to block a site based on its MAC address, make a bridge and add your interface to it. Then route traffic via the bridge and use ebtables to prevent traffic out from the bridge to that mac-address, as such:

ebtables -A OUTPUT -d 00:05:68:02:68:dd -j DROP

It works.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The first part I agree with, however not the second part. As I understand it the next time you would like to send a message to a mac address, the IP address would use the ARP cache to find out the mac address associated with that IP. The IP protocol doesn't stop using mac addresses only because it has once found them out. I mean its IP over Ethernet, and ethernet uses mac addresses to send messages, right? So you would still always need a mac address whenever you'd wish to send an IP message.

Comment: See for complete packet: http://www.laneye.com/network/ethernet-network-packet-holding-an-ip-packet.gif

Comment: Comments above for previous version of answer.

Comment: However the mac source would always be myself, no? There seems to be no --mac-destination option.

Comment: @JohnyTex No, it must be the MAC address of the pc you want to block. After you will have flushed your cache (*ip neigh flush dev eth6*), the other pc will not be able to answer to ARP requests by your pc, hence you will not be able to contact the pc. See http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables.

Comment: From man pages: "Note that this only makes sense for packets coming from an Ethernet device and entering the PREROUTING, FORWARD or INPUT chains." However, I want to block output to that mac.

Comment: @JohnyTex If you really want to block OUTPUT (why??) , then set up a bridge between your ethernet card and a virtual NIC, then go back to using *ebtables*  on the bridge.

Comment: I did that now. I made a bridge, set eth0's master to br0, and use ebtables on br0. It works! I use this approach to simulate a broken network.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that ebtables is only for bridges, and not just any Ethernet interface?

**ebtables - Ethernet bridge frame table administration**